# Is this a good selector or not

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I have some confused about this css selector.
And this code is good or bad performance.

```
[class*=thumb] [class*=_child]> * > h3,
[class*=thumb] [class*=_child]>* p,
[class*=sidebar] [class*=gallery] h3 {
    height:56px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:2px;
    font-weight:400;
}
```

Comment: provide HTML to know the importance of this code with comparison to it.

Comment: If you're asking if it's good or bad performance, you're probably expecting to hear "bad".

Comment: Just adding a common class to those elements would be better. But that depends on if you're able to alter the HTML in any way. Tbh it's not really a question for SO, chances are if you're having to ask that question, you have doubts about it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first selector is first looking for any element with a class that contains "thumb" anywhere within the class name - however I'm not sure how it would perform without the quotes. The same goes for the next selector, but with the "_child" string, and it is looking through all of the children from the previous selector.
It then proceeds to select everything that meets this criteria (which can sometimes cause unexpected problems moving forward), then all child h3's of these.

So it seems like an extremely complex layout that is rife with possible errors, and it could be made a lot simpler by adding a class deeper into the DOM.

Comment: Well if you want to be really pedantic about the quotes, `_child` is not presented as a string in this context *because* the quotes are missing, grammatically it's an identifier instead - but it's up to the implementation how it would treat it internally.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance, the best are IDs, then classes. Having selectors based on attributes is not that great when it comes to performance. Moreover, child selectors (the ones with ">") should be avoided **if you can**.

Anyway, the point is the code you wrote is not performing very well.

Also, this might help you:

> Selectors have an inherent efficiency, and to quote Steve Souders, the
>   order of more to less efficient CSS selectors goes thus:
>
> ```
> ID, e.g. #header
> Class, e.g. .promo
> Type, e.g. div
> Adjacent sibling, e.g. h2 + p
> Child, e.g. li > ul
> Descendant, e.g. ul a
> Universal, i.e. *
> Attribute, e.g. [type="text"]
> Pseudo-classes/-elements, e.g. a:hover
> ```
>
> Source: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Maybe you would also like to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Good luck!